# nextjs meta tag details not appearing on social media post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, meta-tags

I used nextjs builin Head for meta tags. But when I shared my link on  facebook meta tag details not showing. Here is my code:

I added meta tag in my index.js:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <meta
          name="og:title"
          content="I am Jhone. Full Stack Developer."
        />
        <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="my_website_link" />
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="my_website_name" />
        <meta
          property="og:description"
          content="This is my personal blog website."
        />

        <link rel="icon" href="/my.ico" />
      </Head>

      <About />
      <Experience />
      <Services />
      <Portfolio />
      <Contact />
      <Testimonials />
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my code was correct. I fixed the issue after visit https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ then I put my website url and facebook scraper scrape my website and updated meta tags.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this code should be working properly . Try adding meta description without `og` before the `og` description but not sure that will fix your problem.

```js
< meta
property = "description"
content = "This is my personal blog website." />

  <
  meta
property = "og:description"
content = "This is my personal blog website." />
```

And also try removing `.next` folder for removing cached code

Comment: thanks for your answer. Actually my code is correct when I go https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and run scrape it's updating my meta tags